# How To support different Powershell-Versions in Visual Studio Cmdlet DLL

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2019

Our company has some computers with an older version of Powershell as not all machines are allowed to receive certain updates due to dependencies. I am using the nuget-extension **Microsoft.PowerShell.5.1.ReferenceAssemblies** on computers with Powershell 5.1 and **Microsoft.PowerShell.5.0.ReferenceAssemblies** on computers with Powershell 5.0 in my C# CmdLet Project however I can not use both together.

How can I support multiple Powershell versions in my C# CmdLet project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [PowerShellStandard.Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShellStandard.Library) package to create modules (cmdlets) that run across multiple versions and even editions; i.e., they run on both Windows PowerShell and PowerShell [Core].

- Use **version 3** to create cmdlets that run on PowerShell version 3 and later.

  - Curiously, the latest 3.x package published is `3.0.0-preview-02`, from 2018 - I don't know why.
- Use **version 5.1** to create cmdlets that run on PowerShell version 5.1 and later.

See the [PowerShell Standard](https://github.com/powershell/powershellstandard) GitHub repo for more information.

Note:

- Said [PowerShellStandard.Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShellStandard.Library) package is meant **for developing code that runs *from inside PowerShell*** on a given machine; that is, it *needs an existing PowerShell installation*.
- By contrast, the following packages allow you to ***bundle* PowerShell with your application**:

  - [Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK/) - for building PowerShell *Core* applications, based on .NET Core (cross-platform).
  - [Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies/) - for building *Windows PowerShell* applications, based on the .NET Framework (Windows-only)