# C# Powershell in Runspace - How can i get "Format-List" to work?

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

Im currently writing a Contact Manager for our Exchange Online Tenant in C# using the Powershell-Commands and Runspaces from "System.Management.Automation" and "System.Management.Automation.Runspaces" respectively. Its working fine for adding Contacts to the GAL. But im stuck at editing Contacts.

I need to get the Contact Details with the Powershell Commands. The code i can execute looks like this:

```
var command = new PSCommand();
command.AddCommand("Get-Contact");
command.AddParameter("Identity", "someContact");
```

However: This gives me just the Contact-Name, of course. I would need to extend that Command. The equivalent native Powershell-Command i need to execute looks like this:

```
Get-Contact -Identity "someContact" | Format-List
```

When i try to somehow add that "Format-List" to the Command Scheme from above - for example like this:

```
var command = new PSCommand();
command.AddCommand("Get-Contact");
command.AddParameter("Identity", "someContact");
command.AddCommand("Format-List");
```

I get an Exception, telling me that "Format-List" is not the Name of a Cmdlet or anything ... I also tried adding it with AddParameter or even AddArgument - none of these work, i always end up with Errors.

Using Google i found threads here on Stackoverflow, where People passed a Script with the "AddScript()"-Command. But when i do something like this:

```
AddScript("Get-Contact -Identity 'someContact' | Format-List");
```

It tells me, that the Syntax is not recognized because that Remote-Powershell is running in No-Language Mode. I have no clue, how to change that Language Mode neither if it is even possible.

Below is the Full Code i use to execute Remote-Powershell-Commands on our Exchange Online Tenant:

```
        // sPass Variable in SecureString umwandeln (Passwort muss ein SecureString
        // sein, sonst wird es von WSManConnectionInfo nicht akzeptiert!)
        SecureString ssPass = new NetworkCredential("", sPass).SecurePassword;

        // Exchange Online Credentials vorbereiten
        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(sUserAndMail, ssPass);

        // Connection zu Exchange Online mit der URL vorbereiten und Authentication Mode auf Basic setzen
        WSManConnectionInfo wsEOConnInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(sURI), sSchema, credential);
        wsEOConnInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
        wsEOConnInfo.IdleTimeout = 60000;

        // Runspace erstellen, in dem die Powershell-Befehle ausgeführt werden
        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(wsEOConnInfo))
        {
            // Connection herstellen
            runspace.Open();

            // Prüfen, ob Connection existiert. Wenn ja, Commands ausführen
            if (runspace.RunspaceStateInfo.State == RunspaceState.Opened)
            {
                PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

                // Zunächst die ExecutionPolicy auf RemoteSigned für den aktuellen Benutzer setzen. 
                // Andernfalls stehen die MailContact-Befehle der Remote-Powershell nicht zur Verfügung.
                ps.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "RemoteSigned").AddParameter("Scope", "CurrentUser");
                ps.Invoke();

                // Nun den Befehl auf Basis des Use-Cases zusammenstellen
                switch (SearchCaseValue)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        // Hier den Befehl zum Suchen des Kontakts auf Basis des Namens
                        var command = new PSCommand();
                        command.AddCommand("Get-Contact");
                        command.AddParameter("Identity", "*" + tb_SearchTerm.Text + "*");

                        // Kommando zusammensetzen und die Ausführung in diesem Runspace festlegen
                        ps.Commands = command;
                        ps.Runspace = runspace;

                        // Kommando ausführen
                        try
                        {
                            // Den Output des Invokes einer Collection zum Zugriff auf die Inhalte zuweisen
                            Collection<PSObject> psOutput = ps.Invoke();

                            // Einen neuen StringBuilder instantiieren
                            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

                            // Wenn der Inhalt der Collection nicht leer ist, dann jede Zeile des Powershell-Ouputs
                            // aus der Collection in neue Zeilen des StringBuilders schreiben
                            foreach (PSObject outputItem in psOutput)
                            {
                                lb_SearchResults.Items.Add(outputItem.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                        }

                        // Hintergrundfarbe der Listbox ändern, da nun Ergebnisse darin angezeigt werden
                        // und den Button zum Reset der Ergebnisse aktivieren
                        lb_SearchResults.BackColor = Color.White;
                        panel_SearchInProgress.Visible = false;
                        bt_ResetSearchResults.Enabled = true;

                        // Runspace Schließen
                        runspace.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2:
                    {
                        // Hier den Befehl zum Suchen des Kontakts auf Basis der eMail-Adresse erstellen
                        var command = new PSCommand();
                        command.AddCommand("Get-Contact");
                        command.AddParameter("Filter", "((WindowsEmailAddress -like '*" + tb_SearchTerm.Text + "*'))");

                        // Kommando zusammensetzen und die Ausführung in diesem Runspace festlegen
                        ps.Commands = command;
                        ps.Runspace = runspace;

                        // Kommando ausführen
                        try
                        {
                            // Den Output des Invokes einer Collection zum Zugriff auf die Inhalte zuweisen
                            Collection<PSObject> psOutput = ps.Invoke();

                            // Einen neuen StringBuilder instantiieren
                            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

                            // Wenn der Inhalt der Collection nicht leer ist, dann jede Zeile des Powershell-Ouputs
                            // aus der Collection in neue Zeilen des StringBuilders schreiben
                            foreach (PSObject outputItem in psOutput)
                            {
                                lb_SearchResults.Items.Add(outputItem.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                        }

                        // Hintergrundfarbe der Listbox ändern, da nun Ergebnisse darin angezeigt werden
                        // und den Button zum Reset der Ergebnisse aktivieren
                        lb_SearchResults.BackColor = Color.White;
                        panel_SearchInProgress.Visible = false;
                        bt_ResetSearchResults.Enabled = true;

                        // Runspace Schließen
                        runspace.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                }    
            }
            // Runspace schließen, falls nicht bereits geschehen. Wichtig, da in Exchange Online
            // nur maximal 3 Runspaces (Connections) gleichzeitig offen sein dürfen!
            runspace.Dispose();
        }
```

I hope you find this excerpt useful for nailing down the Problem. Sorry for the German Comments in there. I need to get track of what i do, you know?! :-)

So ... can you tell me how to pass "Format-List" to that Remote Powershell without using a Script?

Many thanks for your help in advance!
Steffen

Comment: The `Get-Contact` cmdlet is going to run _on Microsofts server_ - and Microsoft obviously doesn't want you to just be able to run _anything_, so they only allow you to execute a restrictive set of commands and not run arbitrary code blocks (hence "NoLanguage" mode). You will have to feed the output from the remote runspace back to a local runspace if you want to process/format it further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PSObject` returned by `ps.Invoke()` contains all the properties of object. You can get values of all properties.
Just try this

```
ICollection<PSObject> psOutput = ps.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject outputItem in psOutput)
{                                
     var name = outputItem.Members["Name"].Value.ToString();
     var distinguishedName = outputItem.Members["DistinguishedName"].Value.ToString();
     var displayName = outputItem.Members["DisplayName"].Value.ToString();
     var lName = outputItem.Members["LastName"].Value.ToString();

}
```

Just enter the name of property you want to get and it will return you the value of that property.

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution! I wasnt aware that all i need is inside that Object already. Now it makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: Great pointer. Note that while working with the members of [`System.Management.Automation.PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSObject) (such as `.Members` and `.Properties`) is definitely an option, it is much more convenient to use `dynamic` variables, which allow direct member access (e.g., `foreach (dynamic outputItem in psOutput) { var name = outputItem.Name; }`)

Answer (score 3):

Note:

- The ***following* section** shows how to **further process objects obtained from a *remote* PowerShell runspace in a *local* runspace**, which in this case is necessary for security reasons.

  - Here, the **[`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list)** command had to be applied *locally*, but note that it is generally *not* necessary to call `Format-*` cmdlets to work with objects returned from PowerShell SDK calls - see next point; you only need `Format-*` if you want to create a *for-display, string* representation of objects, as you would see in a PowerShell console (terminal).
- The ***bottom* section** discusses **how to process objects returned from PowerShell SDK calls *in general***.

  - As it turns out, working directly with the output objects as *data* is what Steffen truly wanted.

---

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) provided the crucial pointers in a comment:

- For security reasons, **your remote runspace is constrained both with respect to the [*language mode*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Modes) and what specific *cmdlets you are allowed to execute*.**

  - The `NoLanguage` mode prevents use of *PowerShell code* of any kind, which rules out use of the [`.AddScript()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.AddScript) method.
  - Seemingly, use of the `Format-List` cmdlet isn't permitted.
- If you do need to apply `Format-List` to the remote runspace's output, you will need to **use a *second* `PowerShell` instance for *local* execution of [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list), to which you pass the remote runspace's output** - see below.

  - As others have implied, **`Format-List` is only required if you want a *for-display-only*, *string* representation of the output objects, as normally shown in a PowerShell console (terminal).**

    - Otherwise, **to *process data*, simply work with the returned objects and their properties directly**, as shown in the bottom section.
  - Also, `Format-List` doesn't itself output *strings*, but *objects* containing *formatting instructions*; to turn the latter into the formatted string representations they encode, pass them to the [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) cmdlet.

A simplified example:

```cs
PowerShell psRemote = PowerShell.Create();
// Set up the remote runspace ...

PowerShell psLocal = PowerShell.Create();
// NO setup required for a local runspace.

using (psRemote)
using (psLocal) 
{

  // Get output from the remote runspace.
  var remoteOutput = psRemote.AddCommand("Get-Date").Invoke();

  // Pass the output to the local runspace for display formatting.
  foreach (var o in psLocal
                     .AddCommand("Format-List")
                     .AddCommand("Out-String")
                     .Invoke(remoteOutput)) 
  {
    // Print each object's display representation (a single, multi-line string)
    // To get the representation *line by line*, insert `.AddParameter("Stream")`
    // before the .Invoke()
    Console.WriteLine(o);
  }

}
```

---

**Working directly with output objects from PowerShell SDK calls:**

[Muhammad Arsalan Altaf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66552794/45375) shows one way of processing the collection of [`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSObject) instances returned from the non-generic [`.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke) method call, using the `PSObject` type's reflection members such as `.Members` and `.Properties`.

However, since `PSObject` implements the [`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider) interface, you can use the [DLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/dynamic-language-runtime-overview), via **`dynamic` variables**, which **greatly simplifies things**:

Instead of:

```
foreach (PSObject outputItem in ps.Invoke())
{                                
     string name = outputItem.Properties["Name"].Value;
     // ...
}
```

thanks to typing the enumeration variable `dynamic`, you can simply do:

```
foreach (dynamic outputItem in ps.Invoke())
{                                
     string name = outputItem.Name; // use direct property access via the DLR
     // ...
}
```

***In general* it is preferable to use the *generic* form of the `.Invoke()` method (e.g., `ps.Invoke<FileInfo>()`)** so as to get early-bound, static typing.

However, this **isn't always an option**, namely:

- If the **output objects are dynamic objects of type `PSObject`**, which applies to:

  - **`[pscustomobject]` instances**, which are dynamically constructed custom objects ultimately implemented by `PSObject`.
  - **objects returned via [*remoting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote)**, as in your case, where the original .NET type identity is typically *lost*, and `PSObject` instances are used to *emulate* the original type - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for an overview of the XML-based serialization that PowerShell uses for remoting and an explanation of when type fidelity is lost.
- If the **output objects aren't all of the *same type***.

  - However, you can use the `as` operator or a `switch` expression or statement to obtain strongly typed objects wrapped in `PSObject` instances later, using the `.BaseObject` property.

The following **sample code** illustrates **object-processing approaches**:

- You can compile this code as a console application, provided you have added a reference to a PowerShell SDK NuGet package - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63316570/45375).

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace demo
{

  class ConsoleApp
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
      {

        // Use `dynamic` to enumerate the *Collection<PSObject>* instance that is 
        // returned from the non-generic .Invoke() call.
        // This is necessary for:
        //   - [pscustomobject] instances
        //   - "rehydrated" object instances received via *remoting* that have
        //     lost their original type identity ([psobject] == [pscustomobject])
        //   - multiple objects that don't all have the same type.
        foreach (dynamic o in ps.AddScript("[pscustomobject] @{ Foo = 42 }").Invoke())
        {
          // Note: Trying to access a nonexistent property quietly returns null.
          Console.WriteLine($"Dynamic: {o.Foo}"); // -> 42
        }

        ps.Commands.Clear();

        // If the return objects *all have the same type* (other than PSObject),
        // use the generic form of the .Invoke() method and specify that time <T>
        // This returns a *Collection<T>* instance, the members of which you
        // access with early binding, as usual.
        foreach (DateTime o in ps.AddCommand("Get-Date").Invoke<DateTime>())
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"Static: {o.Year}"); // -> this year
        }

        ps.Commands.Clear();

        // *Hybrid approach* for *non-PSCustomObjects* of *non-uniform type*
        // Work with Collection<PSObject>, but use `.BaseObject as <T>`
        // to work with statically typed objects.
        // Here, a `switch` expression (C# 8+) is used, but note that with `as`, when `<T>` is a *value type*,
        // `as <T>?` must be used, i.e. a *nullable* type.
        foreach (PSObject o in ps.AddCommand("Get-Date").AddStatement().AddCommand("Get-Item").AddArgument("~").AddStatement().AddCommand("Get-Location").Invoke())
        {
          Console.WriteLine(
            o.BaseObject switch
            {
              DateTime dt => $"DateTime: {dt}",
              DirectoryInfo fi => $"DirectoryInfo: {fi}",
              _ => $"Other ({o.BaseObject.GetType().FullName}): {o.BaseObject}"
            }
          );
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

The above prints something like the following:

```
Dynamic: 42
Static: 2021
DateTime: 3/10/2021 10:39:36 AM
DirectoryInfo: /Users/jdoe
Other (System.Management.Automation.PathInfo): /Users/jdoe/Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Help me understand why you need to pass your Contact object to `Format-Table`. This is basically destroying the Contact Object itself. Format-Table is just a way to layout a PSObject to the PS Host, once you pass an object to this function said object will lose all its properties and methods.

I'll show you an example of what I mean with an AD User Object.

Without Format-Table:

```
PS C:\> $aduser=Get-ADuser -Filter *|select -First 1

PS C:\> $aduser.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                         
True     False    ADUser                                   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount                   

PS C:\> $aduser.psobject.Properties.Name
DistinguishedName
Enabled
GivenName
Name
ObjectClass
ObjectGUID
SamAccountName
SID
Surname
UserPrincipalName
PropertyNames
AddedProperties
RemovedProperties
ModifiedProperties
PropertyCount
```

With Format-Table:

```
PS C:\> $aduser=Get-ADuser -Filter *|select -First 1|format-table

PS C:\> $aduser.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                         
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                     

PS C:\> $aduser.psobject.Properties.name
Count
Length
LongLength
Rank
SyncRoot
IsReadOnly
IsFixedSize
IsSynchronized
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It does. I wasnt aware that the Output of the Command's Result is not the same compared to the Content of the acutal PSObject. This makes perfect sense. Thank you.