In C# how to exit the PowerShell execution using the Exit command
my C# code invokes PowerShell scripts to do somthing. However after the script is executed there is always a "powershell.exe" process existing on the system's Task Manager list. I want to have it killed programmatically.
I tried using:
powerShell.AddScript(@"[Environment::exit(0)");
The "powershell.exe" process was killed BUT there is always a PSRemotingTransportException thrown.
I tried using powerShell.AddCommand("Exit"); but there is an error saying "Exit" is not a valid cmdlet.
Could anyone please advise how to kill the powershell process? Thanks a lot!

Is your powershell object in a using statement or declaration?

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76398401/10024425

Are you manually creating an out-of-process runspace to host the code? If so, dispose of that once your done with it

PowerShell object can be wrapped in a using statement to dispose of it correctly when done, e.g. a working example:
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddScript("Get-Process");
    var coll = ps.Invoke();
    foreach (var proc in coll)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(proc.Properties["name"].Value);
    }
}

