# How can I use Powershell command Get-Mpthreat in C# (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, xaml

I am currently doing a school internship and should now display the threats history. I've been stuck here for several hours and just can't get any further.

I don't know which "packages" I need for using, nor what kind of code is required.

Sorry for my bad englisch im actually a german student.

I tried using system diagnosis after my supervisor recommended it, but I don't really know what to do with it.

Comment: Use powershell by opening a PS window and then type https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/get-mpthreatdetection?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63314496/how-to-support-different-powershell-versions-in-visual-studio-cmdlet-dll/63316570#63316570, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73981548/get-windowsdriver-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet/73999216#73999216, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76392385/executing-a-powershell-script-from-multiple-environments-result-in-different-out/76398401#76398401, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71838868/process-exited-never-fires/71846819#71846819

Comment: Also, [Choosing the right PowerShell NuGet package for your .NET project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/choosing-the-right-nuget-package?view=powershell-7.2)